# How to use SplitOn with singleInstance?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app with a sql trigger that gets multiple rows.
I need to split on the rows so that I have a better overview about the actions I do per row.

Now I would like that the logic app is only working on one row at a time.

What would be the best solution for that since 
`"operationOptions": "singleInstance",` and

```
"runtimeConfiguration": {
    "concurrency": {
        "runs": 1
    }
},
```

are not working with `splitOn`.

I was also thinking about calling another logic app and have the logic app use a runtimeConfiguration but that sounds just like an ugly workaround.

**Edit:**

The row is atomic, and no sorting is needed. Each row can be worked on separately and independent of other data.

As fare as I can tell I wouldn't use a foreach for that since than one failure within a row will lead to a failed logic app.
If one dataset (row) other should also be tried and the error should be easily visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are seeing the expected behavior.  Keep in mind, the split happens in the trigger, not the workflow.  BizTalk works the same way except it's a bit more obvious there.

You don't want concurrent processing, you want ordered processing.  Right now, the most direct way to handle this is by Foreach'ing over the collection.  Though waiting ~3 weeks might be a better option.

One decision point will be weather the atomicity is the collection or the item.  Also, you'll need to know if overlapping batches are ok or not.

For instance, if you need to process all items in order, with batch level validation, Foreach with concurrency = 1 is what you need.

Comment: I don't need the items in order, each item is atomic.
My goal is to minimize the load on a system that has to be called within the workflow.

A foreach leads to the problem that one error within one row will lead to a stop of the logic app as fare as i can tell.

Comment: @onefox All you need to do is put the risky Actions in a Scope, then configure a RunAfter - Failed, which behaves like a Catch Block.  Then the Logic App can continue after an exception.

Comment: but than i don't have an overview over all the failed messages or? I mean the over all logic app will just show success right?

Comment: @onefox That depends on you.  You can write it to return any response you need depending on the circumstances.  A collection of the success messages and a collection of the failed messages.  You can write it to do anything you want.  I'm just telling you how to recover from the fault internally so you can continue.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will check it out in 2 weeks and take a look if the new implementation works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Today (as of 2018-03-06) concurrency control is not supported for split-on triggers.

Having said that, concurrency control should be enabled for all trigger types (including split-on triggers) within the next 2-3 weeks.

In the interim you could remove the `splitOn` property on your trigger and set its concurrency limit to 1. This will start a single run for the entire collection of items, but you can use a `foreach` loop in your definition to limit concurrency as well. The drawback here is that the trigger will wait until the run as a whole is completed (all items are processed), so the throughput will not be optimal.

Comment: Also I will only have 1 logic app running here so an error within one of the thousand "row" will stop the whole app right?

Comment: if any of the items failed the run would be marked as failed, but the foreach loop would still process all items (i.e. there is no 'fail early' mechanism). You would then need to review results of the foreach to identify which items failed.

Comment: is there a github or any way to get change log information? I only found the Release notes within azure.

Comment: at this time release notes are the only source